# Issue Creating Text Generation Tool in Maya

Tags: python, maya, autodesk

folks, thanks for taking the time to read this! Soooooooo...I'm trying to create a text generation tool in Maya using text curves, but I can't seem to get it to work. The idea is that I enter text into the tool, and after pressing the "Create Text" button, that text would turn into a textcurve piece of geometry, but no matter what I do, I seem to get errors.

Is there any chance somebody might know what I can do to remedy the situation?

Thanks for taking the time to read this! Cheers!

```
import sys
import os
import maya.cmds as mc
outputText = 'Hello World'
def UI ():
    if mc.window('textGenerator', exists = True):
        mc.deleteUI('textGenerator')
    mc.window('textGenerator')
    mc.columnLayout()
    mc.text('Enter text here: ')
    mc.textFieldGrp()
    mc.button(label = 'Create Text', command = 'buttonPress()')
    mc.showWindow('textGenerator')
def buttonPress():
    finalName = mc.textFieldGrp()
    mc.textCurves(finalName)
    sys.stdout.write (outputText)

    mc.textCurves(t=outputText)

UI()
```

Comment: I've just corrected my code review, there were a wrong variable passed throught and you were missing the -t flag on line 15. (i haven't maya before so i couldn't test it live :) )

Answer (score 0):

You have sevzral problems in your code, you have to encapsulate your ui elements into a variable (or at least, name them properly) :

```
textInput = mc.textFieldGrp()
```

Secondly, never use comma to put your command, and use partial or lambda to pass variables to function (read some of my others posts on this subject or find posts from theodox)

```
from functools import partial
mc.button(label = 'Create Text', command = partial(buttonPress, textInput))
```

Last part of your code :

```
def buttonPress(textFieldGrpName, *args):
    # *args is just here to skip a default argument pass as last by maya
    # query the input text in the text field grp
    finalName = mc.textFieldGrp(textFieldGrpName, q=1, text=1)
    mc.textCurves(t=finalName)
    sys.stdout.write (outputText)
    mc.textCurves(t=outputText)
```